# generate random numbers in c and write into a file

Tags: c

I was trying to generate some random numbers in a range and write those numbers into a file, this is what I wrote but instead of generating 15 sets of numbers it only generated one set. I tried use another for loop to do thcan some one help me with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp =fopen ("boundary.dat","w");
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    double xmax,ymax,zmax;
    double x,y,z;
    int i=0;
    xmax = 4000;
    ymax =4000;
    zmax =4000;

    do 
    {
        i=0;
        i++;
        x=(rand()%4000 - 2000);
        y=(rand()%4000 -2000);
        z=1-x-y;
        printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f \n ", x,y,z);
        fprintf(fp, "%.2f %.2f %.2f \n ", x,y,z);
    }
    while ((abs(z)<=zmax) && (i<15));
        fclose(fp);

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `i` will ***always*** be less than `15`.

Comment: You should also step through the code, line by line, in a debugger. That will help you understand what it *really* does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This have not been tested.**

One problem you are having is resetting your `i` in every iteration of the while loop. The solution is removing the line `i=0;` inside the loop. However, I do instead recommend a for-loop as you have all three statements; an initial value, a condition and an increment.

That would turn it to.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15 && abs(z) <= zmax; ++i) {
    x = (rand()%4000 - 2000);
    y = (rand()%4000 -2000);
    z = 1 - x - y;
    printf ("%.2f %.2f %.2f \n ", x,y,z);
    fprintf (fp, "%.2f %.2f %.2f \n ", x,y,z);
}
fclose(fp);

return 0;
```

*I also took the liberty of adding some spaces. Let the code breath!*

Answer (score 1):

You're setting i = 0 at the beginning of the loop and then instantly incrementing it.  This results in your loop only running 14 times.  In fact, I'm surprised it even does that since your i never gets bigger than 1 (since you're resetting it at the beginning of the loop.  I would guess that the other test condition (abs(z) <=zmax)) is causing the exit from your loop.

Take out i=0 from the beginning of the loop and change your test to be i<16 since you're essentially running from 1 to 15 instead of 0 to 14.

Better yet, don't use a do/while loop and use a

```
for(i=0;i<15;i++) {

    ... other stuff here...

    if(abs(z) > zmax) {
         break;
    }
}
```